# How to show multiple city on map using Google Maps API with latitude and longitude and value?

Tags: javascript

How to show multiple city on map using Google Maps API with latitude and longitude and value?? I need to show following data on google maps

```
 var data = [
             { city:"Absecon,NJ", lat: 2.3, long: -2.3 , value: 1000 },
             { city:"XYZ,NJ", lat: 5.3, long: -7.3 , value: 2300 }
            ]
```

Comment: Are you attempting something? Do you know how to instance a google maps object? Is the first to begin. If not, we are making your job.

Comment: beginner in google map api..

Comment: I tell you the four steps (three mandatory) to achieve a working map. But you need to customize with your data. If you have a problem, explain the problem and share your code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn that we are to help in your problems, but not to make your job. otherwise, I can help you with the javascript object of google maps.

### First

include google maps script.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

### Second

You must to specify where do you starting point

```
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.9496116,-9.2180746);
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 2,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("content"),
            myOptions);
```

### Third

You must to put the cities that you need with latitude and longitude.

```
        var portugal=new google.maps.LatLng(38.9496116,-9.2180746);
        var peru=new google.maps.LatLng(-12.0715472,-77.1634965);
        var ecuador = new google.maps.LatLng(-2.162871,-79.898775);

        var marker1 = new  google.maps.Marker({
              position: portugal,
              map: map,
              title:"Portugal"
          });

        var marker2 = new  google.maps.Marker({
              position: peru,
              map: map,
              title:"Perú"
          });

        var marker3 = new  google.maps.Marker({
              position: ecuador,
              map: map,
              title:"Ecuador"
          });
```

### Fourth (optional)

Set window information:

```
        var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<strong>Portugal</strong><p> Milharado, Casal Arneiro Mafra<br>Lisboa, Portugal  <br>Tel: (+351) 219 668 320, Fax: (+351) 219 662 745'
        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
          infowindow1.open(map,marker1);
        });
```

That's all.
You can see it working here:

http://mecal-sa.com/seccion.php?s=8

Good luck